# how to send form values to a server, database , or email

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I  want to  have my Html form values sent and stored on a  database or a server after the user hits submit. I'm new to programming, so I have no idea how to get this accomplished. Moreover, I dont really understand how it works. after the form values are sent to the server, how are they stored? because I want to be able access them later.
Also, I was hoping that I could do all this by using javascript & xml? because I dont know any server side code. I've checked this site, and tried to google for answers, but all the things that I found were either too specific or obscure(too advanced for me to understand). any commentary, or script, or recommended websites or books would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To submit values to a server, you need server-side code to accept them.

If you don't want to learn a server-side programming language, you can just use a Google Docs form.

Answer (score 1):

Decompose the problem into its pieces and solve them separately.  I see at least three:

- How to create a form in an HTML page and POST it to an HTTP listener running on a web/app server
- How to persist values into a database
- How to query a database for values

The precise answer to your question depends on what language/platform you want to use.  It could be LAMP (Linux/Apache/MySQL/PHP), Java (JSP/servlets, JDBC and MySQL), .NET, etc.

Comment: I know this is way too late, but i would like to thank you. This was such an easy and simple question, and you really took the time to answer it.

Comment: Never too late.  I appreciate you making the effort.  I wouldn't have remembered such a thing if I were in your position.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have a hard time finding that sweet spot between "too specific and too obscure", especially here, as you are asking answerers to encapsulate a broad process.

Html values are gathered in the browser via input elements (ex. text boxes, radio buttons, etc.), and when you submit the form some client-side mechanics need to be in place to `POST` those values to the server.

On the web server, your application must be able to receive those values from the `POST` request, turn them into db-objects or write them to files.

In short, Javascript is *predominantly* the client-side piece of the puzzle. HTML and XML are markup languages often understood by both client and server, so they are used often as formats to for both sides to toss back and forth.

What server side programming language are you trying to learn?

Three key steps for you to study are:

1. Constructing an HTML form, and submitting its data via a `POST` request.
2. Writing server side code (determined by the 'stack' you are working with Java, PHP, Ruby, .Net, etc.) to receive this POST, and do something with it.
3. Persist the data somewhere (determined by your DB and/or file format choice).

Comment: Thanks. Your answer was really helpful. I planning on learning PHP.

Comment: No problem. Mark whichever answer you feel is most appropriate.